# POST JSON Parameter to REST HTTPS URL using HTTP Builder in Groovy script

Tags: json, rest, jenkins, groovy, servicenow

I am trying to POST JSON Parameter to REST HTTPS URL using HTTP Builder in my Jenkins Job using Groovy script.
Below is my script :-

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://restservice.appshop.com/' )
def postBody = [name: 'bob', title: 'customer'] // will be url-encoded

http.post( path: '/', body: postBody,
           requestContentType: URLENC ) { resp ->

  println "POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
  assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 201
}
```

I got below error :-

**unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.httpbuilder**

I tried using @Grab also but still got the error only.

Kindly help me out to use this HTTP Builder.

Comment: Please update your snippet to include the @Grab that you are attempting.

Comment: @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )

Comment: Where does servicenow come in?

Comment: Hi Joey, I want to create a change in service now using Jenkins. Is there any possible way to do it ?